# Are [button] and [buttons] duplicate tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, merge, retagging

Is there a difference between the two tags [button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/button) and [buttons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buttons)? If not, perhaps someone can merge the tags and add one as a synonym for the other?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah I can merge & synonymize the two unless there are objections (which I very much doubt).

Generally we prefer the plural form for the tag, so both would be rolled up into [buttons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buttons). Any objections?

---

I went and made them synonyms.

Comment: No, go ahead Ben!